# how to dynamically change product version in wix during each msi creation

Tags: python-2.7, wix, wix3.7

I have a script where i get the version number of my product to a variable 'PRODUCTVERSION' i.e,

```
PRODUCTVERSION= subprocess.check_output('svnversion c:\sandbox -n', shell=False)
```

I want to pass this variable 'PRODUCTVERSION' as a msbuild property to wix. Below is the code which i tried but ending up with an error saying,

```
light.exe : error LGHT0001: Illegal characters in path.
```

Here's my script,

```
def build(self,projpath):
    PRODUCTVERSION= subprocess.check_output('svnversion c:\sandbox -n', shell=False)
    arg1 = '/t:Rebuild'
    arg2 = '/p:Configuration=Release'
    arg3 = '/p:Platform=x86'
    arg4 = '/p:ProductVersion=%PRODUCTVERSION%'
    p = subprocess.call([self.msbuild,projpath,arg1,arg2,arg3])
```

where properties in my wix projects is,

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
  <ProductVersion>$(ProductVersion)</ProductVersion>
  <ProjectGuid>{d559ac98-4dc7-4078-b054-fe0da8363ad0}</ProjectGuid>
  <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  <OutputName>myapp.$(ProductVersion)</OutputName>
  <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
  <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
  <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
  <WixVariables>Version=$(ProductVersion)</WixVariables>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I want to display my output name as 'myapp-2.0.PRODUCTVERSION' ,where PRODUCTVERSION is the version number what i get from my python script.Please help me find a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/light.htm) suggests that for the ProductVersion Light is expecting something in the format x.x.x.x.

If you want to get your MSI named with the version, I've always used a post-build command to rename the file, thus...

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName).msi" DestinationFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName)_v%(myVersionNumer).msi" />
    <Delete Files=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName).msi" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: I want PRODUCTVERSION which i send as a property to wix to be in %(myVersionNumber).How would i use that?

Comment: I think this may be what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233143/anyway-to-create-a-custom-msbuild-property-in-wix-wxs-file

Answer (score 0):

```
def build(self,projpath):
    PRODUCTVERSION = subprocess.check_output('svnversion c:\my path\to svn\ -n', shell=False)
    arg1 = '/t:Rebuild'
    arg2 = '/p:Configuration=Release'
    arg3 = '/p:Platform=x86'
    arg4 = '/p:ProductVersion=%s' %(PRODUCTVERSION)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(([self.msbuild,projpath,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4]), shell=True, 
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    while True:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()                        
        wx.Yield()
        if not line: break
    proc.wait()
```

and in the wixproject pass the above arguments as a MSBuild property and in post build,

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<Copy SourceFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName)-$(ProductVersion).msi" DestinationFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName)-$(ProductVersion).msi" />
<Delete Files=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName).msi" />
</Target>
```